# Beta-testing of products inside KiK

Tags: kik

Is it possible to publish application in Kik, but restrict access for limited number of users?
Something like Facebook sandbox mode.

Thanks,
Serg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kik is simply a mobile web browser. Your webapps can run on any users device without Kik's permission. So there many means by which you can accomplish what you described.

Kik itself doesn't have a service to do this yet but that doesn't mean you cannot do it.

Comment: Actually, Kik is not just a mobile web browser. It introduces various specific APIs. Thus, QA should test specific cases inside Kik. 
But thank you for the answer!